# Convert apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 ingress manifest to apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, nginx-ingress

I had installed an ran a kubernetes cluster with an nginx ingress earlier this year. Though it had little issues, it worked fine. For the ingress, I used the tag

> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1

However, I have recently installed the latest version of (kubernetes 1.22) which only allows for

> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

The problem i'm having is using my old yaml configuration with the new format.

My yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services : "chatserver"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:     
      - path: /api/auth/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: um-service 
          servicePort: 5001
      - path: /api/system/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: system-service
          servicePort: 5002
       - path: /api/news/*
        backend:
          serviceName: news-service 
          servicePort: 5003
      - path: /api/tasks/*
        # pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: tasks-service
          servicePort: 5004
      - path: /api/chats/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: chatserver 
          servicePort: 5500
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 5000
```

my new manifest looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/auth/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: um-service 
            port: 
              number: 5001
      - path: /api/system/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: system-service 
            port: 
              number: 5002
      - path: /api/chats/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: chatserver
            port: 
              number: 5050
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-service
            port: 
              number: 5000
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

How do I convert this to use the new apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 tag?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately there isn't too much difference between the API versions in terms of the YAML. Here's an example of `networking.k8s.io/v1` from the [Kubernetes Docs](https://docs.k8s.io).

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

The main change for you would have to do with the how the `backend` blocks are done. For example:

```yaml
backend:
  serviceName: tasks-service
  servicePort: 5004
```

would need to become:

```yaml
backend:
  service:
    name: "tasks-service"
    port:
      number: 5004
```

Comment: when I do that, it does not route properly as before, some of the paths don't work. As you can see, I don't have a host but several backend paths. Do I need to do something more?

Comment: Can you post the updated version of the YAML manifest for the ingress?

Comment: I have posted the current YAML manifest

Comment: I'd remove the rewrite target annotation, that was just part of the example, didn't necessarily mean for you to copy that. You should also reuse your previous annotations from the old manifest.

Comment: kindly check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475221/exposing-several-socket-io-paths-in-ingress